# How to write/say the opposite of 100+?

Tags: slang, antonyms

Example:

> "I probably sent out, 100+ emails today."
>
> 100+
>
> one-hundred-plus (?)

How would you say or write the opposite?

> "Because your paper's rating is -100- you are now required to gain outside approval before we will consider publishing your paper."
>
> -100- (?)
>
> negative-one-hundred-minus (?)

I am looking for a smooth flowing and less verbose way to say "negative-one-hundred-minus" and a short hand way to write -100-.

I understand that I could word the sentence differently to say "less than negative one hundred or write <-100 but I wan to see what other ways this can be expressed.

Comment: The minus sign character should be used instead of the hyphen. Example: "less than −100" instead of "less than -100". The first has the correct length, but is unfortunately harder to type.

Comment: Because negative numbers are contrived rather than conceptually opaque, you will have to use the language of maths. This offers fewer alternatives than everyday English.

Comment: @Fengyang Wang: Which minus sign character? Different fonts will have lines of different lengths. Different handwriting styles will be infinitely variable and non-reproducible. It becomes silly demanding rules that can't apply universally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Unlike the hyphen character (-), the   U+2212 MINUS SIGN character (–) is specifically defined to represent a negative number. Fonts will design it to look best as a minus sign. It is not a "non-reproducible" and "silly" rule.

Sometimes, a font might make it look identical to the hyphen, but you cannot be sure of this! In most fonts, the hyphen is a lot shorter. Using the correct character is the only universal way to make negative numbers look like negative numbers.

Comment: @Fengyang Wang: You are banning written script, then?

Comment: Excuse me butting in, but which character is used to represent a minus sign has nothing to do with English and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @FengyangWang What you are calling the “hyphen” character is incorrect. U+002D is HYPHEN-MINUS, while U+2010 is HYPHEN.  That’s because HYPHEN-MINUS has historically been used for both purposes.

Answer (score 1):

First, a note: after years of having studied advanced math, I have never come across any quick or abbreviated way of getting the point across that a number is ever so slightly below negative 100.  Also, just to make this response clear for everyone, remember that numbers such as -103, -117 etc. are technically "less than" the number -100.

It is difficult to come up with exact answers, because I do not fully understand the rating system that you are describing. I am going to go with the assumption that the paper in question had a score of, say, -107, and that a paper has to have a minimum score of -100 to get published without any outside approval.

I might say it like this:

> Because your paper's rating fell shy of the -100 mark, you will need to gain outside approval for publication.

Or, if you wanted to emphasize that the author missed the threshold, but not by much, it might work to say:

> Your paper fell just shy of the -100 mark.  You will need outside approval to publish the paper.

And then, lastly, if you wish to emphasize that the author did a rather poor job, you might say:

> Because your paper's score fell below -100, you will need outside approval to publish it.